# WPF DesignData not working

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, data-binding, design-time

I have a MVVM WPF application with a simple ListView. The ViewModel currently just contains a List property. I added a DesignData/SampleData.xaml file, set its Build Action to "DesignData" and referenced it in the Window's XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="..."
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:local="..."
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="483" Width="932">

    <Grid d:DataContext="{d:DesignData Source=./DesignData/SampleData.xaml}">
```

But nothing shows up in the designer and VS2010 just gives me the following warning:
The file './DesignData/SampleData.xaml' is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' is not set to 'Resource'.

No matter what the "Build Action" it still gives me the same warning.

SampleData.xaml:

```
<MainWindowViewModel xmlns="clr-namespace:..." 
                     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:...">
    <MainWindowViewModel.Orders>
        <local:Order OrderId="1000654321"/>
    </MainWindowViewModel.Orders>
</MainWindowViewModel>
```

Any ideas on how to fix that?

**Edit**:

Project structure
[image: Project Structure]

Comment: What's the application's project structure like?

Comment: Added structure image. Folder names follow the namespace.

Comment: You just made me realize the path is wrong exactly because of the structure. I was thinking it was relative to the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Good stuff, I'm glad I was able to inadvertently help! :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DesignData path is wrong as I thought it was relative to the solution/project whereas it seems it is relative to the containing XAML file.

Comment: It is relative to the current file because that's what your Path value indicates with the `.` in `Source=./DesignData` If you want the path relative to the Project level just drop the `.`